# Delete "Designed by Mage-World" from Copyright bar

Tags: magento

I'm working on a project so I have created an online store using Magento. I have changed the Copyright field in Admin Panel (System -> Configuration -> Design) but it is still printed in my site. Is is possible to delete this message?

Comment: Which them you are using?

Comment: To locate this you need to enable `template path ` Then you can find the exact location

Answer (score 0):

You can remove from footer.phtml

You can find that in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/footer.phtml